# node js asking browser to reload the page

Tags: node.js, meanjs

I want to reload the page after some validations placed at the server side fails.. i have already tried with `res.redirect` `res.location` and `location.reload()` .

I need to place the reloading logic on the server side in nodeJS.

So whenever there is a request from client side this validation gets triggered and if the validation fails i am destroying the window user object but i am unable to reload the page...it's stays on the same same and then all services starts failing..because of user object check now..

Comment: The reload should happen on client side, not on server. On server side you can do the validations and set a variable and on client side check the status of this variable then decide to reload or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do an ajax call you need to reload in the client side browser code based on http response.
if it's a form post you can render whatever html you want back to the client.

A way to build this in your ajax framework would be to: In serverside you could redirect and then clientside, have the code that looks like this (warning this is just psuedo code):

```
if(response.httpStatusCode == 301 or 302)
 window.location(response.headers.location)
```

Comment: Thanks! using the same strategy now.